# Hyperlinked Image Container Too Wide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "row" of three hyperlinked boxes which include a descriptive text at the top and an image below that. However for some reason the container box that I've created left aligns my content, then extends out to be about double the width that I want.

What would be the best way to get it to wrap to just the minimum width required to contain the image and text? Additionally, what makes the container act the way it does now versus just wrapping the minimum width by default?

My code can be found below, as well as on [this jsfiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/mdo1fpc7/). Please also enjoy the beautiful sample picture I found on W3Schools.com:

```css
.smallimgbox {
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.smallimgboxcontainer {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-left: auto;
}

.smallimgbox img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallimgboxcontainer">
  <div class="smallimgbox">
    <a href="">
      <h3>Link #1</h3>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="smallimgbox">
    <a href="">
      <h3>Link #2</h3>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="smallimgbox">
    <a href="">
      <h3>Link #3</h3>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a row divided into 3 boxes with the image and the text centered inside each box.
With your code, at the moment, each `smallimgbox` defaults to the width of the contained img. Then you resize the image to 50% of its container box.

To have the row divided in 3 parts (using floats) you need to specify a width for each, this way:

```
.smallimgbox {
    width: 33.3%:
}
```

If you want the image to be 50% f the container and centered you have to set `margin: 0 auto` and make sure the img is displayed as a block:

```
.smallimgbox img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

At this point you are only missing the text:

```
.smallimgbox {
   text-align: center;
}
```

I updated the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdo1fpc7/8/).

Comment: This solved the issue; I was not thinking of the image resizing as being with respect to the container box.

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the following lines

```
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
```

that denote to take 50% of the parents width. Since your parent does not have a width defined it will set the width to your child's image full width (`400px`).

You have several options:

1) Define a width on your parent (e.g. `300px` and your childs will have a width of `150%` and being on side of each other).

2) Define a width on your childs (e.g. `200px` width on your child's instead of `50%` and your child will be on side of each other).

3) Remove the `50%` width on your childs and each of your childs will be `full width` (which is `400px` on your images).

**4) This is what I think you want:** Define the full width on your parent and set your childs depending on this:

```
.smallimgboxcontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.smallimgbox {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
 }
```